# No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2, centos, linux

I'm using a centos 7 server where I've installed nginx, php, mysql, elsaticsearch and ceated a magento setup.

In the magento admin  > stores > Configuration > catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search I'm getting ***No alive nodes found in your cluster***

Although the indexing is running properly and I can see it in Elasticsearch log.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong over here.

Please have a look at the below given admin configuration.

[image: admin configuration]

When I'm calling from terminal this is what I'm getting

[image]

Below is the indexer result.

[image]

Comment: replace localhost in hostname with 127.0.0.1:9200 then try.

Comment: @Mehran tried it but the result is same.

Answer (score 2):

Did anyone have success fixing this error?

I have the same error, indexing via cli is working but the Storefront and Admin have the error "No alive nodes found in your cluster"

Update:

I resolved my error - issue was CentOS SELinux and permissions set to Enforcing.

Changing SELinux permissions to Permissive resolved the issue for me.

```
setenforce 0
```

Note: I faced the same issue where Indexing worked correct via command line, but not on front/back end admin. This has fixed my issue.. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration
First let's check if your configuration is correct:

Update your host and port: '[host]:[port]'. E.g.: `localhost:9200` in Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search or if you are you are using Elastic Suite in Stores > Configuration > ElasticSuit > Basic configuration as per your setting.

Update your indices alias name and indices name pattern in admin configuration same as above.

Clear cache by going to System > Cache Management or using this command (on your server in Magento installation folder):

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Reindex by visiting System > Index Management or running command below:

## Update catalog search

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

## Or reindex all indexers

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Check Elasticsearch
If the error still stands, it might be the issue with the elasticsearch service on your server. To solve this follow the steps below:

Log into your Magento instance.

Check if the elasticsearch is running:

sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status

Try to start it if it's not running, or restart it if it's running:

## Start elasticsearch

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

## Or restart elasticsearch

```
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

You've found the issue if you encounter an error here and your elasticsearch doesn't start. Solve the issue first. Continue when the elasticsearch starts.

Navigate to your Magento installation folder

Reindex all indexers

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Clear the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Your problem should have been solved by now.

Comment: I did all the above steps, status is still same , as mentioned in the question, indexing is working but issue is coming on Magento admin and storefront.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento and getting 'No alive nodes found in your cluster' error while reindexing.

Make sure you have updated following :

Your Host and port : '[host]:[port]'. Eg: 'es-node1.fqdn:9200, es-node2.fqdn:9200' or 'localhost:9200' in Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.
Update your indices alias name and indices name pattern in admin configuration same as above.
Try this, and clear cache and reindex. It will solve your issue.

If you are using Magento and getting 'No alive nodes found in your cluster' error while reindexing.

Make sure you have updated following :

Your Host and port : '[host]:[port]'. Eg: 'es-node1.fqdn:9200, es-node2.fqdn:9200' or 'localhost:9200' in Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.
Update your indices alias name and indices name pattern in admin configuration same as above.
Try this, and clear cache and reindex. It will solve your issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are closing the Elasticsearch cmd panel. Don't close that window. So that Elasticsearch will be on otherwise it will disable.

After that run these commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the similar issue and i have found that Opensearch was working but still it keep displaying "No alive nodes found in your cluster"
After spending hours i was able to figure out that security issue
Our local website was on http and running the cmd
curl http://localhost:9200
returned
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

On the other side
curl https://localhost:9200 is returning the required result

**Solution**
You need to configure the SSL locally to resolve this issue